# Fast loop alternative for array gen and concat in MATLAB / Octave

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, loops, octave

I have a large file with values, I'm trying to create a waveform with those values.

It takes too long, and since I'm not the best at Octave, I think there may be another way to do this. I'm looking for a faster alternative, one that uses Octave's array handling capabilities instead of me doing a loop, which I assume is slow.

**EDIT**

`csv` is a [1xn] array.

```
csv = csvread('values.csv');

n = length(csv);

t = [0 : 1 / (freq * spc) : 1 / freq];
t = t(2 : length(t));

wave = csv(1) * sin(two_pi_freq * t);

for i = 2 : n

    wave = [wave (csv(i) * sin(two_pi_freq * t))];

endfor
```

Comment: CSV is a 1xn vector? or a matrix?

Comment: @ArthurChamz, I edited the answer based on your additional input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edited answer based on latest comments:*

To avoid any `for` loop, you can multiply your two vectors to obtain an array, then reshape the array to put all the values in line.

The way you are building `t`, it will be of dimension [1xm] *(with `m=length(t)`)*

For a `csv` vector of dimension [1xn], instead of your loop, use:

```
%// generate an array size [nxm] by multiplying [nx1] * [1xm]
wave2 = csv.' * sin(two_pi_freq * t) ;    
wave2 = reshape( wave2.' , [] , length(t)*length(csv) ) ; %// reshape the array in one [1xm*n] line
```

This should replace your last 4 lines of code (the first definition of `wave` and the 3 lines of the loop.